# Bootstrap - 'data-original-title=' appearing grey when I try to create a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="tooltip" data-original-title="title" href="#" id="ttip"></a>
```

the part: 'data-original-title=' appears grey in notepad++ has if something is wrong. It doesnt work. any help? I'm pretty sure I have installed bootstrap java script correctly with the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it appears grey because it's a custom attribute

Answer (score 0):

If the tooltip isn't showing, try to initialize it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#ttip').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at this example. http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vstlu/2/

Also, please be sure to load css/js in the correct oreder as:

```
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap-theme.min.css
jquery.min.js"
bootstrap.min.js
```

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Try these for example (not local files, but to be sure you're loading things correctly, and you can discard external files issues and focus in the code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("enable");
});
</script>
```

try this block ,if you set field value in a page method ,you should use this code snippet after you setting value to initialize tooltip